# Analytics software for responsive website

Tags: testing, mobile, analytics, tablet, usability

We have just implemented responsive webadesign to a part of our website. Now we would like to analyze user behavior on the mobile formats.

Previously, we used Clicktale to analyze user behavior, but the tool can't display behavior in tablet or mobile format. 
Therefore, I search a strong analytics software that can deliver results from a responsive design ?? 
I would prefer some software that can deliver; click test, scrollreach, click flow or a/b test.

I hope you'll be able to help. Thanks.

Heidi

Answer (score 0):

We've used Mixpanel and Heap. Heap is newer but you don't have to be as precise when you mark up your pages. It just captures all the browser events and you have to dig in a bit to figure out which ones signify interesting events. Mixpanel takes a bit more markup behind the scenes. I don't think it has some of the equivalent reports that ClickTale does (like the heatmap).